# Как сделать сайдбар

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать этот блок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь

```
<div class="recently-added col-xl-4">
            <h5>Recently added</h5>
            <p>21 book to read before you die</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Было бы здорово добавить к вопросу код и ваши попытки, описать, что конкретно не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы в bootstrap блоки были на одной строке необходимо все нужные блоки обернуть в блок с классом "row"

**Ответ на Ваш вопрос:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="some-class col-xl-8">
        Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum ...
    </div>
    <div class="recently-added col-xl-4">
        <h5>Recently added</h5>
        <p>21 book to read before you die</p>
    </div>
</div>
```